# Does argocd self heal rollout upgrade done on the cluster by wave?

Tags: service, upgrade, wave, argocd

I am deploying a service through argocd with
SYNC POLICY

- AUTOMATED = True
- PRUNE RESOURCES = True
- SELF HEAL = True

I am using wave https://github.com/wave-k8s/wave to monitor my service deployment with secret as volume mount. When this secret change(which will), wave triggers rolling upgrade for the deployment which will then get the latest secret.

My question is
Does the rolling upgrade happen? If yes, then will argocd auto sync's it to old state after sometime? Or will argocd ignore the rollouts done manually on cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a rolling update is fine and Argo will not fight this. you can validate this by doing a rolling update manually on an application that is managed by Argo (the update should progress w/ no issues)

With that sync policy, you need to make sure that Argo is NOT managing the secret, or that you have an `ignoreDifferences` setting for it - https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/diffing/.